# Creating a new blank row of elements without passing values from row above it

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When a user presses "Add Dates" a new row is generated as expected, but the values are already populated within the new row and they are exactly the same as the initial row. How can I create a blank row?

[image: view]

Snippet of the html page:

```html
<p-dropdown [options]="leaveCodes2" [(ngModel)]="selectedLeaveCode2" placeholder="Leave Code" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date2" [showIcon]="true"  placeholder="From Date" id="setter"></p-calendar> 
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date7" [timeOnly]="true" class="timer" placeholder="Select Time"></p-calendar>
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date3" [showIcon]="true"  placeholder="To Date" id="setter"></p-calendar>
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date8" [timeOnly]="true" class="timer" placeholder="Select Time"></p-calendar>
```

Method to `Add Dates`:

```
dates = [1] //Initializing date array

// Method to add dates on button click for up to 4 dates
onAddClicked() {
  if(this.dates.length < 4)
  this.dates.push(1);
}
```

Code for `Add Dates` Button:

```html
<button pButton type="button" label="Add Dates +" class="ui-button-success" (click)="onAddClicked()"></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think it is good to create a component which holds the input fields. Then you need to have an array with the data and use ngFor on the array of data.

I created an example in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8naua

The sample does not have any styling and uses no types. But it should give you enough info to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is remove `[(ngModel)` from my code.

Updated snippet posted below

```
<p-dropdown [options]="leaveCodes2"  placeholder="Leave Code" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
<p-calendar  [showIcon]="true" placeholder="From Date" id="setter"></p-calendar>
<p-calendar  [timeOnly]="true" class="timer" placeholder="Select Time"></p-calendar>
<p-calendar  [showIcon]="true" placeholder="To Date" id="setter"></p-calendar>
<p-calendar  [timeOnly]="true" class="timer" placeholder="Select Time"></p-calendar>
```